# Disabling responsiveness causes increasing right-side gap on window resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, window-resize

I intend to create a non-responsive Bootstrap template. Because I want to prevent the navbar from collapsing. However when I window resize to a certain level a gap arises

Example

http://bootply.com/render/87304

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the navbar from collapsing, Download the latest version from http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip and compile your own version.

Set @grid-float-breakpoint to 0 in variables.less.

To could also use http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics to do the same.
See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10465

If you don't want to compile anything try: https://github.com/bassjobsen/non-responsive-tb3

**update**
the gap has to do with the fixed width of your container to width: 970px; Note your navbar is not in a container and gets 100% width of the viewport.